# How to get the Hard Drive Serial number?

Tags: c#, wmi

Currently I am using the below code to get the serial number of Hard Drive:

```
private void GetAllDiskDrives()
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

    foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
    {
        HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
        hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
        hd.InterfaceType = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
        hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();//get the serailNumber of diskdrive
        HdCollection.Add(hd);
    }
}

public class HardDrive
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string InterfaceType { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

This code works fine.

But the above code returns all the Drives. I just want to have only specific hard-drive (Not Partition) serial number on which my software is running.

So, how can I get the serial number of hard-drive in which my software is running?

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds like another attempt to reinvent the licensing wheel. So, your customers can't change disk drives?

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are correct.

Comment: @Khushi: some would call that user-unfriendly

Comment: @RodrigoSilva I have found the above code from that question. But it dosn't solve my problem.

Comment: Users will prefer to buy software from someone who allows them to change their hardware.

Comment: @JohnSaunders your opinion is good. But still I will stick with my idea.

Comment: rather than the HDD serial, consider the CPU ID which is less likely to change.  Even better, create a signature of the system: BIOS Ver, CPU ID, VIDEO Make/Model and Windows Serial.  Then, as long as 2 of 3 or 3 of 5 match from the original, consider it valid.  That way users can change stuff without "issues".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia` to find all physical drives.

To find the physical drive your program is loaded from you would have to extract the drive letter from `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`, then load all partitions using `SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive` and then somehow map the desired partition to one of the physical drives from `SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia`.

---

I looked into your problem a little further. It seems to be impossible to correlate partitions and physical drives using just WMI. But using WinAPI directly it is a piece of cake:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(String mountPoint, StringBuilder name, UInt32 bufferLength);

private enum FileAccess : uint
{
    None = 0
}

private enum FileShare : uint
{
    ReadWriteDelete = 0x00000001 | 0x00000002 | 0x00000004 // FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE
}

private enum FileCreation : uint
{
    OpenExisting = 3 // OPEN_EXISTING
}

private enum FileFlags : uint
{
    None = 0
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(String fileName, FileAccess access, FileShare share, IntPtr secAttr,
    FileCreation creation, FileFlags flags, IntPtr templateFile);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

private enum IoControlCode
{
    GetVolumeDiskExtents = 0x00560000 // IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private struct VolumeDiskExtents
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt32 numberOfDiskExtents;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UInt32 diskNumber;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public Int64 startingOffset;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public Int64 extentLength;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean DeviceIoControl(IntPtr device, IoControlCode controlCode, IntPtr inBuffer, UInt32 inBufferSize,
    ref VolumeDiskExtents extents, UInt32 outBufferSize, ref UInt32 bytesReturned, IntPtr overlapped);

public class PhysicalDisk
{
    public PhysicalDisk(String physicalName, String model, String interfaceType, String serialNumber)
    {
        this.PhysicalName = physicalName;
        this.Model = model;
        this.InterfaceType = interfaceType;
        this.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
    public String PhysicalName { get; private set; }
    public String Model { get; private set; }
    public String InterfaceType { get; private set; }
    public String SerialNumber { get; private set; }
}

public PhysicalDisk GetPhysicalDiskFromCurrentDrive()
{
    //
    // Get the drive letter of the drive the executable was loaded from.
    //
    var basePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "");
    var driveLetter = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(basePath);
    // TODO: Validate driveLetter; could also be a UNC path.

    //
    // Get the volume name of the drive letter.
    //
    var volumeNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(65536);
    if (!GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(driveLetter, volumeNameBuffer, (UInt32)volumeNameBuffer.Capacity))
        throw new Win32Exception();
    var volumeName = volumeNameBuffer.ToString().TrimEnd('\\'); // Remove trailing backslash

    //
    // Open the volume and retrieve the disk number.
    //
    UInt32 diskNumber;
    IntPtr volume = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        volume = CreateFile(volumeName, FileAccess.None, FileShare.ReadWriteDelete, IntPtr.Zero,
            FileCreation.OpenExisting, FileFlags.None, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (volume == (IntPtr)(-1)) // INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        {
            volume = IntPtr.Zero;
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        VolumeDiskExtents extents = new VolumeDiskExtents();
        UInt32 bytesReturned = 0;
        if (!DeviceIoControl(volume, IoControlCode.GetVolumeDiskExtents, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
            ref extents, (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(extents), ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Partitions can span more than one disk, we will ignore this case for now.
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365727(v=vs.85).aspx
            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 234 /*ERROR_MORE_DATA*/)
                throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        diskNumber = extents.diskNumber;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (volume != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(volume);
            volume = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    //
    // Build the physical disk name from the disk number.
    //
    String physicalName = ("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE" + diskNumber).Replace("\\", "\\\\");

    //
    // Find information about the physical disk using WMI.
    //
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE DeviceID = \"" + physicalName + "\"");
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
    {
        return new PhysicalDisk(
            obj["DeviceID"].ToString(),
            obj["Model"].ToString(),
            obj["InterfaceType"].ToString(),
            obj["SerialNumber"].ToString()
            );
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: CreateFile must be called with 0 file access rights for it to succeed. It fails with access denied otherwise.

Comment: It's quite possible that the application I tested this in all those years ago was running with admin rights, so `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` on the volume itself worked. The `DeviceIoControl` call still works without any access rights? - Thinking about it, the access mask doesn't make much sense since just the extents are queried. I changed it.

Comment: Yes, it works. At least for getting the volume disk extents.